# Alternatives to <ctime>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I'm looking for a C++11 version of the `<ctime>` library. Were any like this included with C++11?

EDIT:
Anything with more functionality would be perfect!

EDIT 2:
I'm looking to use this with a game I'm making so that I can keep track of total time played. Anything that would help me with that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look at `<chrono>`.

Comment: Was there anything more specific you were looking to do?

Comment: You can can use one of the clocks' `now()` functions twice and subtract.

Comment: last time check `<chrono>` is not available on all the platforms.

Comment: @xiaoyi: The question is specifically about C++11, and it is available in any conformant C++11 implementation.

Comment: Ah, looks like `high_resolution_clock` is not included in the MSDN documentation. However, it's included in VS11 and a call to `Sleep(5647)` produced a timer value of 5647ms. Keep in mind there's `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` for that, but I was never able to use it with GCC.

Comment: @chris Also the mingw32 implementation. I spend hours to add macros to my code to support other platforms, but `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` works for me with g++ 4.7 on linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 includes the `<chrono>` header, which provides different types of clocks (I'll use the high resolution one), that have a `now` function. You can subtract two of these times received from `now()` to get the total number of `<unit>`s (I'll use seconds) between them:

```
using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using unit = std::chrono::seconds;
std::chrono::time_point<clock> startTime = clock::now(); //get starting time

... //do whatever stuff you have to do

std::chrono::time_point<clock> thisTime = clock::now();
long long secondsElapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<unit>(thisTime - startTime).count();

//now use secondsElapsed however you wish
//you can also use other units, such as milliseconds or nanoseconds
```

Do note, however, that `secondsElapsed` is not guaranteed to be positive unless the `is_steady` member of the clock is `true` because that member being `true` means that a subsequent call to `now()` will give a larger number than a former call to `now()`.

Comment: Nit: `system_clock::now()` is a member *function*, so you may want to add parentheses.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin, Thank you for pointing that out. It's absurd that I left them out in both calls and didn't realize.

Comment: Note: you might to mention the value of `is_steady`. This boolean member is `true` only if the values returned by `now()` increase monotically. I would advise *not* using a non steady clock to measure elapsed time.

Comment: I'd recommend against calling the alias `clock` because sometimes other headers include other system headers which can in turn include the header with the function `clock` defined. In any case, I'd actually recommend you *never* name a function/var the same as one in the c standard.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, I guess it was mainly for shortening the example. If this is all local to a scope, then there shouldn't be any problem unless the `clock` function is actually used as well, but naming it differently can't hurt.

Answer (score 9):

Many of the functions in `<ctime>`, notably the `ctime` function itself, have to do with *formatting* dates and times as strings.

C++11 provides a new io-manipulator `std::put_time`, which indeed replaces C-style functions, and is fully compatible with the locale-related features of C++.

Specifically, given a time-point in C-style `tm` format:

```
std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
```

`std::put_time` enables printing this according to any chosen locale, if locale-specific formatting parameters, such as `%c` (locale-specific date/time), `%Ec` (locale specific, extended date/time, such as imperial years for Japan), or `%Z` (time-zone) are used:

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ja_JP.utf8"));
std::cout << "ja_JP: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
std::cout << "ja_JP: " << std::put_time(&tm, "%Ec %Z") << '\n';
```

These calls print something like:

```
2012年11月15日 11時49分04秒 JST     // first call
平成24年11月15日 10時49分05秒 JST   // second call
```

The time-point retrieval functions from `<chrono>`, mentioned in the other answer, can also be converted to a `tm` struct, using the `to_time_t` method, and then used together with `put_time`. This makes the code independent of any C-style function calls, at least on the surface:

```
using namespace std;
auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();

time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
cout << "Locale-specific time now: "
     << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%c %Z") << '\n';
```

Combined with `<chrono>` duration types, this gives great flexibility in calculating and printing dates and times:

```
time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - chrono::hours(48));
cout << "Locale-specific time on the day before yesterday: "
     << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%c %Z") << '\n';
```

These are the headers you need for all the function calls above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
```

**Availability note** I am unsure about MSVC and Clang, but GCC, unfortunately, does not provide the `std::put_time` function just yet: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354.