# Measuring sub-second elapsed time of native C++ on Windows platform

Tags: c++, cpu-usage, timing

What would be a good way to measure sub-second elapsed time of native C++ code on Windows Platform(I am working on Windows Vista, Visual Studio 2010)

I have tried using

```
#include <ctime>

int main()
{    
    clock_t start = clock();
    ... some code
    clock_t end = clock();
    double cpu_time = static_cast<double>(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

but `cpu_time` is always `0`.

Thanks !

Comment: You could try putting the `some code` in a loop and then dividing? Also, try just printing out `end` and `start` and see if they're different at all.

Comment: @chris I have copy of Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012, will give <chrono> a try.

Comment: For older toolsets there is also [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/).

Comment: @newprint, If you're still trying to use/understand it, I remember giving a timer example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390620/alternatives-to-ctime/13390783#13390783), not too long ago.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469715/c-fine-granular-time/13471487#13471487)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter` WinAPI functions. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739265/600135)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all valid and working.  If you're trying to time the execution of a particular piece of code, you should run it through a loop, as suggested by Xymostech.  The main reason being:

- Your code snippet will execute very fast.  In some cases, executing
  the start, code-snippet, and end of your timer the same clock-tick. 
  This will result in `start` holding the same value as `end`, causing
  `cpu_time` to equal zero.

however, there is also the added benefit of being able to calculate the average execution time over many iterations